# Non resonant antenna electrical model

Tags: rf, antenna

I apologize in advance if my question is too naive or incorrect; I am still very new in the difficult domain of RF and antennas.
I know that at the first order, a resonant antenna can be modeled electrically as an RLC tank circuit, where more or less, R is the radiation resistance of the antenna.

Now, let us consider a non resonant antenna. To put flesh on bones, let us even restrict ourselves to horn antennas. This time, it is difficult to imagine there are both L and C components (for this would resonate). Hence my question: At the first order, is a non resonant antenna modeled by an RL or RC circuit? something else?

Comment: in that simple model: simply as R. The feeding transmission line sees the electrical wave impedance (e.g. 50Ω); no power is reflected back. In fact, I often consider antennas to be nothing but (idealizedly) lossless impedance transformers between transmission line impedance and free space impedance. I think the horn antenna illustrates that very neatly!

Comment: Well normally one "matches" antenna to behave like purely resistive 50 ohm loads. If not properly matched it depends on the tuning if the antenna is behaving capacitive or inductive. So to the best of my knowledge there is no correct answer to the question as it is stated right now.

Comment: Christian B. Are you saying that electrical models for antennas are a fiction ? I think the matching and the electrical model are two different things. In a similar manner, you can "match" an RLC tank circuit to make it appear purely resistive at a given frequency, but that does not mean that the circuit does not exist. Furthermore, (ultra) wide band antennas need no matching, and that covers (in my opinion) most of the non resonant antennas I know.